# Duplicate results in prolog

Tags: if-statement, prolog, duplicates

I'm terrible with prolog. I keep getting a duplicate result in this simple code"

```
mates(bob, john).
mates(bob, bill).
mates(andrea, sara).
mates(andrea, bill).
friends(X, Y) :- mates(X, Z), mates(Y, Z).
```

Calling friends(bob, X). I get bob twice. If only I could use and IF statement argh!!!

How can I elimiate duplicate results? IE If(result1 == result2) dont print;

Im looking for similar friends, ie the result should be bob and andrea (because of bill).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be more along these lines?

```
friends( X , Y ) :- mates( X , Y ).
friends( X , Y ) :- mates( X , T ) , mates( T , Y ).
```

If you want similar friends (per your comment below), try:

```
friend( X , Y ) :-
  mates( X , T ) ,
  mates( Y , T ) ,
  X \= Y .
```

The `\=` operator means 'not unifiable with', so that should exclude cases where party A is friends with his- or herself. The exact operator for 'not unifiable with' might vary depending on implementation.

Also bear in mind that the "correct" solution is a bit more convoluted than it might seem the mates relationship is transitive: if Andrea is a mate of Bills, the presumably Bill is a mate of Andrea's. You solution should likely take that into account.

Comment: that gives me all of bob's friends, but I'm looking for the similar friends. The result should be bob and andrea, since they have similar friends. Thanks for the input though

Answer (score 1):

```
mates(bob, john).
mates(bob, bill).
mates(andrea, sara).
mates(andrea, bill).

friends(X, Y) :-
        setof([X,Y],(friends2(X,Y),\+(X=Y)),L),
        append(L0,[[X,Y]|_],L),
        \+(append(_,[[Y,X]|_],L0)).

friends2(X, Y) :- mates(X, Z), mates(Y, Z).
friends2(X, Y) :- mates(X, Z), mates(Z, Y).
friends2(X, Y) :- mates(Z, X), mates(Z, Y).
friends2(X, Y) :- mates(Z, X), mates(Y, Z).
```